# Compare element 0 of two lists of lists; make new list of lists with items in z[0] that are not in x

Tags: python, python-3.x

If `i[0]` of each list in z is not in x, put that z list in g and if it's already in x, put x in g.

```
x = [[68, 40000], [69, 40800.0], [70, 41616.0]]
z = [[62, 0], [63, 0], [64, 0], [65, 0], [66, 0], [67, 0], [68, 0], [69, 0], [70, 0]]
```

I want the result to be:

```
g = [[62, 0], [63, 0], [64, 0], [65, 0], [66, 0], [67,0], [68, 40000], [69, 40800], [70, 41616]]
```

I tried various combinations of:

```
g = [z for x, x in zip(z, x) if z[0] not in x]
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [[68, 40000], [69, 40800.0], [70, 41616.0]]
z = [[62, 0], [63, 0], [64, 0], [65, 0], [66, 0], [67, 0], [68, 0], [69, 0], [70, 0]]

dct_x = {v[0]: v for v in x}
g = [dct_x.get(v[0], v) for v in z]
print(g)
```

Prints:

```
[[62, 0], [63, 0], [64, 0], [65, 0], [66, 0], [67, 0], [68, 40000], [69, 40800.0], [70, 41616.0]]
```